# Docker container saying "cannot mount volume over existing file, file exists" even though no such volumes have been explicitely mounted

Tags: docker

I ran a container using an image, and inside the container I edited a file called loolwsd.xml. Then I ran `docker commit` on that running container, and then stopped that container. Then when I tried to run my new container with the committed image, I get the error:

> ERROR: for collabora_2021-08-03  Cannot create container for service nginx: cannot mount volume over existing file, file exists /var/lib/docker/overlay2/2969d8db91d122d7d95c4439c26814d4c9e2a5542edc7cb7254013201dd7cc7b/merged/etc/loolwsd/loolwsd.xml

I am confused. The folder `2969...` keeps changing after I keep attempting to run the new image. I've tried `docker volume prune` but the error still persists...

My docker file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    image: collabora/code:2021-08-03
    container_name: collabora_2021-08-03
    ports:
      - "9980:9980"
    environment:
      - domain= ...
    restart: always 
networks:
  default:
    external: true
    name: nginx-network
```

Full error:

```
$ docker-compose up

Creating collabora_2021-08-03 ... error

ERROR: for collabora_2021-08-03  Cannot create container for service nginx: invalid volume specification: '/home/ian/docker-servers/collabora:etc/loolwsd/loolwsd.xml:rw': invalid mount config for type "bind": invalid mount path: 'etc/loolwsd/loolwsd.xml' mount path must be absolute

ERROR: for nginx  Cannot create container for service nginx: invalid volume specification: '/home/ian/docker-servers/collabora:etc/loolwsd/loolwsd.xml:rw': invalid mount config for type "bind": invalid mount path: 'etc/loolwsd/loolwsd.xml' mount path must be absolute
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

Please, does anyone know how to tackle this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]; nothing you show here references that file?  Note that `docker commit` intrinsically is _not_ reproducible and using it is rarely a best practice; a better approach would be to write a Dockerfile that includes the file you need.

Comment: @DavidMaze Yeah that is what I ended up doing to make it work. Building a docker file that copied a local file into a container to build the image worked, instead of committing an already running container with changes inside.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are creating a volume in your docker image, and set bind path to etc/loolwsd/loolwsd.xml

If so, docker tries to find etc/... which doesn't exists and can't be found

You should use /etc/... instead of etc/...